# async with bot: AttributeError: __aenter__

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

I've got a following error when running my code:

```
  File "C:\discord bot\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\punk102rus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\punk102rus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\discord bot\main.py", line 14, in main
    async with bot:
AttributeError: __aenter__
```

How can I fix it? Here is the code that I've used:

````
from ast import alias
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
import asyncio

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
        
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        
        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio/best'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None
        self.ytdl = YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS)

     
    def search_yt(self, item):
        if item.startswith("https://"):
            title = self.ytdl.extract_info(item, download=False)["title"]
            return{'source':item, 'title':title}
        search = VideosSearch(item, limit=1)
        return{'source':search.result()["result"][0]["link"], 'title':search.result()["result"][0]["title"]}

    async def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

           
            self.music_queue.pop(0)
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: self.ytdl.extract_info(m_url, download=False))
            song = data['url']
            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song, executable= "ffmpeg.exe", **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.play_next(), self.bot.loop))
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    
    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']
           
            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

               
                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("```Could not connect to the voice channel```")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])
          
            self.music_queue.pop(0)
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: self.ytdl.extract_info(m_url, download=False))
            song = data['url']
            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song, executable= "ffmpeg.exe", **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.play_next(), self.bot.loop))

        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p","playing"], help="Plays a selected song from youtube")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)
        try:
            voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        except:
            await ctx.send("```You need to connect to a voice channel first!```")
            return
        if self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("```Could not download the song. Incorrect format try another keyword. This could be due to playlist or a livestream format.```")
            else:
                if self.is_playing:
                    await ctx.send(f"**#{len(self.music_queue)+2} -'{song['title']}'** added to the queue")  
                else:
                    await ctx.send(f"**'{song['title']}'** added to the queue")  
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="pause", help="Pauses the current song being played")
    async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.is_paused = False
            self.is_playing = True
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name = "resume", aliases=["r"], help="Resumes playing with the discord bot")
    async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.is_paused = False
            self.is_playing = True
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help="Skips the current song being played")
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            
            await self.play_music(ctx)


    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Displays the current songs in queue")
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        retval = ""
        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            retval += f"#{i+1} -" + self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + "\n"

        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(f"```queue:\n{retval}```")
        else:
            await ctx.send("```No music in queue```")

    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Stops the music and clears the queue")
    async def clear(self, ctx):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("```Music queue cleared```")

    @commands.command(name="stop", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="Kick the bot from VC")
    async def dc(self, ctx):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()
    
    @commands.command(name="remove", help="Removes last song added to queue")
    async def re(self, ctx):
        self.music_queue.pop()
        await ctx.send("```last song removed```")
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have a proper **aenter** method defined in your music_cog class. The async with bot syntax requires that the object used in the async with statement has an **aenter** and **aexit** methods.

```
class music_cog(commands.Cog):
  async def __aenter__(self):
    # You can add any setup code you need here
    return self

  async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
    # You can add any cleanup code here
    pass
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how to do this, just add the aenter and aexit methods to the beginning of the code? I'm just a beginner programmer and I don't understand these things at all yet

Comment: In general the way bot will use your class contain use of those two methods (while creating and deleting your object in simple terms) so the methods needs to be accessible in your class. You may use just standard implementations for the start (as the one I presented above) and if needed add some additional operations to be invoked during creation or deletion of your objects.

Comment: I added these 2 methods, but the error still remains(